# Remove the last single quote from a vector of strings in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 vectors like this

```
SS <- "Length','Breadth'"
BB <- "Area','Volume','Circumference'"
```

I am trying to use these 2 vectors in my sql query this way

```
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={Oracle in instantclient11_1};DbQ=zzzzz;UId=xxxxxx;Pwd=yyyyyy;")

sql<-paste0( "SELECT * FROM Measurements
                WHERE Unit IN ('",SS,"')
                AND target IN ('",BB,"')")
df <- sqlQuery(conn,sql)
```

This gives me an error saying "**quoted string not properly terminated**" 
After working through the problem, I realized the last single quote is the one causing it. I am not sure how to remove it.

My **desired output** is

```
SS <- "Length','Breadth"
BB <- "Area','Volume','Circumference"
```

Can some one provide some directions on this?

Comment: `SS<-sub('\'$', '', SS)` should work.

Comment: You can use `sub("'$", "", SS)`

Comment: Thank you. both the solutions worked.

Comment: You can make the code easier to read and safer if you use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `"'$"` in `sub`

```
sub("'$", "", SS)
```